# What is the number of days between two dates?

Tags: c#, datetime

We want to find the number of days between two dates. This is simple when the dates are in the same year.

Is there a built-in way to do this if the dates are in different years, or do we just have to loop through each year?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Subtracting a date from another yields a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties.aspx). You can use this to determine the number of whole days using the `Days` property, or whole and fractional days using the `TotalDays` property.

```
DateTime start = ...;
DateTime end = ...;

int wholeDays = (end - start).Days;
```

or

```
double totalAndPartialDays = (end - start).TotalDays;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `TotalDays`.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, thanks for explaining subtracting dates yields a TimeSpan.

Answer (score 3):

you can probably do something like:

```
TimeSpan ts = endDate - startDate;
ts.Days
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you missing?

```
DateTime - DateTime => Timespan
```

and `Timespan` has `Days` and `TotalDays` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(date1.Year - 2, date1.Month, date1.Day);

    Int32 difference = date1.Subtract(date2).Days;
```